# Start index with certain value zipWithIndex in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I want to start value of indexes in data frame with certain value instead of default value zero, if there is any parameter we can use for zipWithIndex() in pyspark.

Comment: What's the bigger problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: if there is re run for the job, it takes max from the previous job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following solution will help to start zipwithIndex with default value.

```
df = df_child.rdd.zipWithIndex().map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1] + index)).toDF()
```

where index is default number you want to start with zipWithIndex.