# Is there a way to add a column with range of values to a Spark Dataframe?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe: df1 as below:

```
age = spark.createDataFrame(["10","11","13"], "string").toDF("age")
age.show()
+---+
|age|
+---+
| 10|
| 11|
| 13|
+---+
```

I have a requirement of adding a row number column to the dataframe to make it:

```
+---+------+
|age|col_id|
+---+------+
| 10|   1  |
| 11|   2  |
| 13|   3  |
+---+------+
```

None of the columns in my dataframe contains unique values.
I tried to use `F.monotonically_increasing_id())` but it is just producing random numbers in increasing order.

```
>>> age = spark.createDataFrame(["10","11","13"], "string").toDF("age").withColumn("rowId1", F.monotonically_increasing_id())
>>> age
DataFrame[age: string, rowId1: bigint]
>>> age.show
<bound method DataFrame.show of DataFrame[age: string, rowId1: bigint]>
>>> age.show()
+---+-----------+
|age|     rowId1|
+---+-----------+
| 10|17179869184|
| 11|42949672960|
| 13|60129542144|
+---+-----------+
```

Since I don't have any column with unique data, I am worried about using windowing functions and generate `row_numbers`.
So, is there a way I can add a column with `row_count` to the dataframe that gives:

```
+---+------+
|age|col_id|
+---+------+
| 10|   1  |
| 11|   2  |
| 13|   3  |
+---+------+
```

If windowing function is the only way to implement, how can I make sure all the data comes under a single partition ?
or if there is a way to implement the same without using windowing functions, how to implement it ?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: None of the columns in my dataframe doesn't contain unique values.    2 negations...

Comment: @thebluephantom Fixed the grammar. Any idea to implement ?

Comment: yes sill het back later zipWithIndex

Comment: will get bak later. use zipWithIndex

Comment: But `zipWithIndex` is based on the file order and the order within the file. Not sure if we can assume that condition. [Docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/api/python/pyspark.html): *The ordering is first based on the partition index and then the ordering of items within each partition. So the first item in the first partition gets index 0, and the last item in the last partition receives the largest index.*

Comment: so what is the problem then? narrow transformation

Comment: My understanding was that the ID should be based on some kind of ordering. If this is not the case I agree with `zipWithIndex`.
@metatdata Can you clarify to requirement?

Comment: @thebluephantom I was able to do it using zipWithIndex as given in my answer. Please take a look at it. Will there be any performance hit if I use the method given in my answer ?

Comment: but the whole poing us you are supposed to credit those that help here.

Comment: the other has performance due to partitionBy()

Comment: Well I think I kept my part of the deal.

Comment: And I kept mine too. Accepted the answer. But to start the value of ID from `1` and not zero, what should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `zipWithIndex`.

I could not find code I did myself in the past yesterday as I was busy working on issues, but here is a good post that explains it. https://sqlandhadoop.com/pyspark-zipwithindex-example/

pyspark different to Scala.

Other answer not good for performance - going to single Executor. `zipWithIndex` is `narrow transformation` so it works per `partition`.

Here goes, you can tailor accordingly:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, LongType
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df1 = spark.createDataFrame([ ('abc'),('2'),('3'),('4'), ('abc'),('2'),('3'),('4'), ('abc'),('2'),('3'),('4') ], StringType())

schema = StructType(df1.schema.fields[:] + [StructField("index", LongType(), True)])
rdd = df1.rdd.zipWithIndex()
rdd1 = rdd.map(lambda row: tuple(row[0].asDict()[c] for c in schema.fieldNames()[:-1]) + (row[1],))
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(rdd1, schema)
df1.show()
```

returns:

```
+-----+-----+
|value|index|
+-----+-----+
|  abc|    0|
|    2|    1|
|    3|    2|
|    4|    3|
|  abc|    4|
|    2|    5|
|    3|    6|
|    4|    7|
|  abc|    8|
|    2|    9|
|    3|   10|
|    4|   11|
+-----+-----+
```

Comment: THe index value is starting from 0. Can you let me know how to start it from 1 ? That is my actual requirement.

Comment: just do a withColumn and add 1 to that value

Answer (score 0):

**Assumption**: This answer is based on the assumption that the order of `col_id` should depend on the `age` column. If the assumption does not hold true the other suggested solution is the in the questions comments mentioned `zipWithIndex`. An example usage of `zipWithIndex` can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60146037/14338716).

**Proposed solution**:
You can use a `window` with an empty `partitionBy` and the the row number to get the expected numbers.

```py
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

windowSpec = Window.partitionBy().orderBy(F.col('age').asc())
age = age.withColumn(
    'col_id',
    F.row_number().over(windowSpec)
)
```

[EDIT] Add assumption of requirements and reference to alternative solution.

Comment: This is true, but it would solve the issue. What solution would you suggest otherwise?